# What is this plant with many purple blossoms in autumn?

Tags: identification

Who can identify this plant for me? As you can see, it thrives well in autumn e.g. here in Central Europe. What is its name?

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the (unintended) duplicate.

Comment: No problem - these things happen.Especially with id questions. Don't worry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [amaranthus caudatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaranthus_caudatus) a decorative plant that also goes by *love-lies-bleeding*, *foxtail amaranth* or *hanging amaranth.*

It's an annual that is often grown in gardens or parks for his decorative inflorescence. Note that while you found this one in Europe, it's originally from South America.

Amaranth is grown not only for decorative purposes, it's [seeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaranth#Amaranth_seed) are an important dietary staple in Southern America and the leaves and other parts are edible as well.